# Align a slicer when file opens

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, slicers

I have a workbook that has several pivot tables linked to 1 slicer as in Year & Week, but I would like to auto update these when my file opens as part of the check routine and I am getting more and more confused looking at whats online

I currently have the below but I am unsure how to get it to reference the slicer against the value B13?
I have tried various example but either get the

> 1004 or 438 error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please as it only needs to be loaded this way the first time the file is opened as its then down to the individual to filter as needed

I have tried the code below and various others but seem to be going round in circles

```
Dim pf As PivotField

CYear = Worksheets("LiveStaffLoader").Range("B11").Value
CWN = Worksheets("LiveStaffLoader").Range("B12").Value
PWN = Worksheets("LiveStaffLoader").Range("B13").Value

PivotTables("PivotTable2").ClearAllFilters
 Set pf = ActiveSheet.SlicerCaches("Year") _
  .VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[PivotTable2].[Year].&[" &        Worksheets("LiveStaffLoader").Range("B13").Value & "]")
```

Comment: You have a string inside the array function. Did you mean to put that as the address of `Range`?

Comment: As a range if possible, but I am shooting in the dark to be honest as I haven't adjusted slicers with vba before.  Can you suggest where how I can get it to align to the week number and year please.  Year is under Year and week under weekno in my table

Comment: Sorry, just read the message, yes as a range please or a ref as in CYear